# Android Resources$NotFoundException inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-resources, android-music-player, android-handler

i have build a musicplayer project with a swipeview (2 fragments). one fragments has the start button, when i klick the start button, the another fragments shows the metadata informations of the song with also a seekbar.
my problem is to get the current Time by a song when its playing.

the code of the fragment looks like that:

```
public static class SongParameterFragment extends Fragment {

    public SeekBar seekBar;
    static int fragmentNR;
    public ImageView cover;
    public TextView songParameter, songDuration;
    runnableTimeline timelineMonitor;

    public SongParameterFragment(int position) {
        this.fragmentNR = position;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(com.example.swipeview3.R.layout.song_parameters, container, false);
        cover = (ImageView)v.findViewById(com.example.swipeview3.R.id.imageView1);
        songParameter = (TextView)v.findViewById(com.example.swipeview3.R.id.textView_SongParameter);
        songDuration  = (TextView)v.findViewById(com.example.swipeview3.R.id.textView_SongDuration);
        seekBar = (SeekBar)v.findViewById(com.example.swipeview3.R.id.seekBar);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);

        timelineMonitor = new runnableTimeline();
        Thread thread = new Thread(timelineMonitor);
        thread.start();


        return v;
    }

    SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChangeListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if(fromUser){
                if(MainActivity.mp != null){
                    int totalDuration = MainActivity.mp.getDuration();
                    int currentDuration = totalDuration * progress/100;
                    MainActivity.mp.seekTo(currentDuration);
                }
            }

        }
    };


    private class runnableTimeline implements Runnable{

        int totalDuration, currentDuration, currentTime;

        @Override
        public void run() {
                while(true){
                if(MainActivity.mp != null){
                    totalDuration = MainActivity.mp.getDuration();
                    currentDuration = MainActivity.mp.getCurrentPosition();
                    currentTime = (int)(100 * currentDuration/totalDuration);
                    seekBar.setProgress(currentTime);

                }               
                else {
                    seekBar.setProgress(0);
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this code works fine. but when i want to show the current Time of the song (or the time of the progress of a song) i put the code `songDuration.setText(currentTime);` in the run()-method after `seekBar.setProgress(currentTime);` and get the following error-message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(10902): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-33702
E/AndroidRuntime(10902): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
E/AndroidRuntime(10902):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:260)
E/AndroidRuntime(10902):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3680)
E/AndroidRuntime(10902):    at com.example.swipeview3.MainActivity$SongParameterFragment$runnableTimeline.run(MainActivity.java:311)
E/AndroidRuntime(10902):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

anyone an idea or an advice for a solution? thx in advance

**EDIT 1:**
hi guys, this is the error message, when i change the code `currentDuration.setText(currentTime);` in `currentDuration.setText("" + currentTime);` and also in `currentDuration.setText(Integer.toString(currentTime));` the error-message is:

```
02-05 19:26:32.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14221): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-33924
02-05 19:26:32.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14221): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
02-05 19:26:32.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14221):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4286)
02-05 19:26:32.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14221):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:885)
02-05 19:26:32.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14221):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12881)
02-05 19:26:32.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14221):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12881)
02-05 19:26:32.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14221):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12881)
02-05 19:26:32.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14221):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12881)
02-05 19:26:32.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14221):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12881)
02-05 19:26:32.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14221):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12881)
02-05 19:26:32.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14221):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12881)
02-05 19:26:32.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14221):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:268)
02-05 19:26:32.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14221):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12881)
02-05 19:26:32.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14221):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:7184)
02-05 19:26:32.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14221):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3513)
02-05 19:26:32.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14221):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3369)
02-05 19:26:32.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14221):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3344)
02-05 19:26:32.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14221):    at com.example.swipeview3.MainActivity$SongParameterFragment$runnableTimeline.run(MainActivity.java:311)
02-05 19:26:32.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14221):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

i do not think, that the line `currentDuration.setText(currentTime);` is the problem. Should i implement a handler or something like that?

EDIT 2:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActivityCommunicator {

public static MediaPlayer mp;
SongParameterFragment f2;
PlayerFragment f1;
SectionsPagerAdapter mySectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.example.swipeview3.R.layout.main);

    mySectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(com.example.swipeview3.R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mySectionsPagerAdapter);

}

public void PlayKlick(View v) {
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), com.example.swipeview3.R.raw.music);
    mp.start();
    f2 = (SongParameterFragment)mySectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(1);      
    f2.passDataToFragment(loadMp3DataFile());
}

private String loadMp3DataFile() {
    ......
    return mp3_parameter;
}

public void StopKlick(View v) {
    mp.stop();      
}

public void ExitKlick(View v) {
    mp.stop();
    this.finish();
}

@Override
public void passDataToActivity(String someValue) {
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(com.example.swipeview3.R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


//  ------------------------------#########################------------------------------
//  ------------------------------#########################------------------------------

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private PlayerFragment f1;  
    private SongParameterFragment f2;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if(position == 0) {
            if (f1 == null) {               
                f1 = new PlayerFragment(position);          
            }           
            return f1;      
        }       
        else {
            if (f2 == null) {               
                f2 = new SongParameterFragment(position);           
                }           
            return f2;  
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(com.example.swipeview3.R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase();
        case 1:
            return getString(com.example.swipeview3.R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

//  ------------------------------#########################------------------------------
//  ------------------------------#########################------------------------------

public class PlayerFragment extends Fragment {

    int fragmentNR;
    public Button btnPlay, btnStop, btnExit;
    public MediaPlayer mp;

    public PlayerFragment(int position) {
        this.fragmentNR = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       Log.e("Test", "hello");
       //position = getArguments().getInt("position");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(com.example.swipeview3.R.layout.player, container, false);

        btnPlay = (Button)v.findViewById(com.example.swipeview3.R.id.button_play);
        btnStop = (Button)v.findViewById(com.example.swipeview3.R.id.button_stop);
        btnExit = (Button)v.findViewById(com.example.swipeview3.R.id.button_exit);

        return v;
    }       
}

//  ------------------------------#########################------------------------------   
//  ------------------------------#########################------------------------------

 public static class SongParameterFragment extends Fragment {

    public SeekBar seekBar;
    static int fragmentNR;
    public ImageView cover;
    public TextView songParameter, songDuration;
    runnableTimeline timelineMonitor;

    public SongParameterFragment(int position) {
        this.fragmentNR = position;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(com.example.swipeview3.R.layout.song_parameters, container, false);
        cover = (ImageView)v.findViewById(com.example.swipeview3.R.id.imageView1);
        songParameter = (TextView)v.findViewById(com.example.swipeview3.R.id.textView_SongParameter);
        songDuration  = (TextView)v.findViewById(com.example.swipeview3.R.id.textView_SongDuration);
        seekBar = (SeekBar)v.findViewById(com.example.swipeview3.R.id.seekBar);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);

        timelineMonitor = new runnableTimeline();
        Thread thread = new Thread(timelineMonitor);
        thread.start();


        return v;
    }

    SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChangeListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if(fromUser){
                if(MainActivity.mp != null){
                    int totalDuration = MainActivity.mp.getDuration();
                    int currentDuration = totalDuration * progress/100;
                    MainActivity.mp.seekTo(currentDuration);
                }
            }

        }
    };


    private class runnableTimeline implements Runnable{

        int totalDuration, currentDuration, currentTime;

        @Override
        public void run() {
                while(true){
                if(MainActivity.mp != null){
                    totalDuration = MainActivity.mp.getDuration();
                    currentDuration = MainActivity.mp.getCurrentPosition();
                    currentTime = (int)(100 * currentDuration/totalDuration);
                    seekBar.setProgress(currentTime);
Line 311:               songDuration.setText("" + currentTime); 
                }               
                else {
                    seekBar.setProgress(0);
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

no one an idea? :/

Comment: I think the error is in your layout.

Comment: no, it cant be aerilys. i dont think so. i think i have to implement a handler, but i am not sure.

Comment: What line is this in your code `MainActivity.java:311`? Also if you add line numbers to your code it will be better to read it.

Comment: hi rotary heart,
i added the full code and marked the line 311. this is the line, where the code sondDuration.setText(...); is written

Answer (score 9):

Your current time is an int value. Android is detecting that int as a resource. So, you can put setText("" + currentTime).
This way, it will be handled as a string and probably will solve your problem.

Comment: Even better: `setText(Integer.toString(currentTime))` which is more efficient

Comment: hi guys, thanks for your help. i tried both variations and got errors.

Comment: Ok, that's a different problem. You're trying to modify UI from your runnableTimeline class that is a different thread, and Android doesn't allow it. Thus, as you've suggested, you need to implement a hander to receive the progress and update the view on your UI thread. You can find several example on Google. I leave here the first one: [link](http://android.programmerguru.com/android-seekbar-example/). Good luck!